# Is there a way to view the errors associated with loading a project file in Rider?

Tags: rider

We have a large (466 project) visual studio solution. When using project rider, one of the projects doesn't fully load, and the solution explorer shows (with errors) after the project name. Is there anywhere in Rider to view said errors?

Comment: It also seems like the issue is related to the references, as that section isn't populated in the solution explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to open "Log" tool window:

[image]

Also you can run Rider in [internal mode](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207327910) in execute "Reload project and show logs" context action from Solution Explorer. It that case Rider will reload a project, collect all information from MsBuild and show log file in editor.

Comment: That definitely did it!